# Function that prints all the strings in A that start with '-1' or with '1'

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to write a function that can print all the strings that start with '-1' or with '1'.

This is currently what I have so far:

```
def Sample(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == 1 or A[i] == -1 : print (A[i])
```

I am wondering if I am doing this right. Many thanks in advance.

The solution provided in the previous post did not work for me. I asked the question again and the solution works for me.

Comment: You asked this question this morning what was wrong with the answers then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed for your snippet:

```
def Sample(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i][0] == '1' or A[i][0:2] == '-1' :
            print (A[i])

Sample(['345', '-1', '-9876', '-100', '123'])
```

Output:

```
-1
-100
123
```

Comment: This solution is very good and helped me out in learning the kinks of my program.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A` is a list or tuple, you have to loop through its elements, then check if those element starts with `"1"` or `"-1"` using [`startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function:

```
for e in A: # e will be the element
    if e.startswith("1") or e.startswith("-1"):
        print e
```

Comment: The question is tagged `python-3.x`: `print` should be function form.

Comment: e.startswith(('1','-1'))

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.startswith(prefix)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check whether the string `str` starts with the `prefix`. The `prefix` can be a substring or a tuple of substrings:

```
>>> def sample(a):
...     for s in a:
...         if s.startswith(('1', '-1')):
...             print(s)
...
>>> sample(['345', '-1', '-9876', '-100', '123'])
-1
-100
123
```

Comment: I think you are incorrect according to help Help on built-in function startswith:

startswith(...)
    S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool
    
    Return True if S starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
    With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
    With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
    prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.

Comment: @PyNEwbie, The argument of `str.startswith` can be a tuple of strings. Please read the documentation carefully.

Comment: @PyNEwbie, According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith): `prefix` can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.

Comment: So what are you saying, you claim in your answer that a is a string to check for b - I don't see that in the docs str is the string to be checked from my read

Comment: look at my comment below in your case it should be str.startswith('1','-1')

Comment: @PyNEwbie, `str.startswith('1','-1')` is equivalent to `'1'.startswith('-1')` which yield always `False`.

Comment: Not according to my version of Python >>> mylist = ['1234','-1234','xd2','1']
>>> for item in mylist:
 if item.startswith(('1','-1')):
  print item

  
1234
-1234
1

Comment: @PyNEwbie, I mean: in your comment, you used `str.startswith('1','-1')` literally. (`str.startswith`: unbound method, `'1', -'1'` without parentheses). http://ideone.com/e113hn

Comment: @PyNEwbie, Ah, it seems like you are seeing my initial answer which is edited in grace time, aren't you?